# Return the page to the client, and do a final IO blocking operation

Tags: php, io

When generating a page with PHP:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
// generate the HTML output
// HTML finished here
send_output_to_client();       // <-- how to do this?

perform_blocking_IO_operation();      // this can last 100 ms or more, this will not output anything anymore, 
                                      // only internal logging IO operations
?>
```

how to ask PHP to send the output to the client and **don't wait for `perform_blocking_IO_operation()` to finish**?

Since `perform_blocking_IO_operation()` can last 100 ms or more, I'd like to avoid this unnecessary waiting time for the client.

Comment: @Andy I thought `flush` or `ob_flush` would send data to client, but not close the HTTP connection. In my case, I would like to terminate the connection.

Comment: 100ms is 0.1s. not really going to be noticeable, surely...

Comment: @ADyson Currently I serve the page to client in less than 100 ms; I don't want to double my page generation time because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flushing as mentioned above or RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thank you and welcome to SO. Please elaborate with sample code and/or reference to documentation for this post to be a complete answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).